# How do i get rid of these white areas around the hair particles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, transparency, hair, grease-pencil

i have tried everything, from playing with alpha blend, messing with the light source, and even changing the light of the world. But the white wont go away. It only shows up when its in front of another object which is a grease pencil that was colored in and blurred with an effect.Any ideas?[image]

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue with Cycles. https://imgur.com/NpmbazM If none of contributors will solve it please append your simplified blend (delete all that does not participate on issue) via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @vklidu okay i uploaded the blend file into the exchange.

Comment: Thanks but to let us to access the file you have to copy paste given code into your question :-) via edit.

Comment: i fixed it i think. i made a dynamic sky , change the grass material to an object and just lowered the strength of the dynamic sky, i think it has something to do with transparency,but the lines are gone now and thats all that matters.

Comment: Great you solved it. Just reminder - this site maintained to answer Q, but also be a knowledge base for others to find a solutions. It would be great if you can provide a regular answer (what cause the issue and (or) how did you solve it) so others can learn from issues of others (instead of writing a new Q and wait for A). Thank you for keeping this site usefull - in matters too :)